# htaccess : redirect an image path to a PHP script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like the following image URL

```
http://www.example.com/image-provider/article/1275449_inline3_scale_700xauto.jpg
```

to be redirected to the following PHP script that will actually generate the content

```
http://www.example.com/image-provider?url=article/1275449_inline3_scale_700xauto.jpg
```

I've tried the following syntax in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/image-provider/(.*)$ image-provider?url=$1 [L]
```

With no success so far:I still get a 404. Is there something wrong in my .htaccess ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(image-provider)/(.+)$ $1?url=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Couple of issues in your rule:

1. Leading slash is not matched in `.htaccess`
2. You must use `.+` to avoid matching `/image-provider/` as an URI.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply and for pointing out my mistakes. However I still get a 404. Is there any way to debug what the mod_rewrite is doing ?

Comment: ok my bad, it works. I juste add another rule in my .htaccess that messed things up. Thanks